# Recogida de variables en html para insertar en una tabla mediante php

Tags: php, base-de-datos

Tengo un formulario creado en **html** con **checkbox**, los cuales si estan checkeados significa verdadero y si no, falso.

```
 <form method="post" action="formulario-marcas.php">
                <p>
                    <label>Nombre: </label><input type="text" name="nombre" 
 id="nombre" required></input>
              </p>
                <p>
                  <label>Dirección: <input type="text" name="direccion" 
id="direccion"></input></label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="orden-direccion" id="orden- 
direccion">Orden
                    <input type="checkbox" name="visualizar-direccion" 
 id="visualizar-direccion">Visualizar
              </p>
                <p>
                  <label>CP: <input type="number" name="cp" id="cp"></input> 
 </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="orden-cp" id="orden- 
cp">Orden
                    <input type="checkbox" name="visualizar-cp" 
 id="visualizar-cp">Visualizar
              </p>
                <p>
                  <label>Localidad: <input type="text" name="localidad" 
 id="localidad"></input></label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="orden-localidad" id="orden-localidad">Orden
                    <input type="checkbox" name="visualizar-localidad" id="visualizar-localidad">Visualizar
              </p>
                <p>
                  <label>Provincia: <input type="text" name="provincia" id="provincia"></input></label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="orden-provincia" id="orden-provincia">Orden
                    <input type="checkbox" name="visualizar-provincia" id="visualizar-provincia">Visualizar
              </p>
                <p>
                  <label>Teléfono1: <input type="number" name="telefono1" id="telefono1"></input></label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="orden-tlf1" id="orden-tlf1">Orden
                    <input type="checkbox" name="visualizar-tlf1" id="visualizar-tlf1">Visualizar
              </p>
                <p>
                  <label>Teléfono2: <input type="number"  name="telefono2" id="telefono2"></input></label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="orden-tlf2" id="orden-tlf2">Orden
                    <input type="checkbox" name="visualizar-tlf2" id="visualizar-tlf2">Visualizar
              </p>
                <p>
                  <label>Imagen: <input type="text" name="imagen" id="imagen"></input></label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="orden-imagen" id="orden-imagen">Orden
                    <input type="checkbox" name="visualizar-imagen" id="visualizar-imagen">Visualizar
              </p>
                <p>
                  <label>Email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email"></input></label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="orden-email" id="orden-email">Orden
                    <input type="checkbox" name="visualizar-email" id="visualizar-email">Visualizar
                </p>
              <input type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
            </form>
```

Ahora quiero ponerlo en php y añadirlos en una tabla, pero no me funciona, no se porque, me da fallo justo al insertar valores.

```
<?php
    //// Recoger checkbox orden ////
    if($_POST['orden-direccion']){
        $_POST['orden-direccion'] = 'Verdadero';
    }else{
        $_POST['orden-direccion'] = 'Falso';
        }

    if($_POST['orden-cp']){
        $_POST['orden-cp'] = 'Verdadero';
    }else{
        $_POST['orden-cp'] = 'Falso';
        }

    if($_POST['orden-localidad']){
        $_POST['orden-localidad'] = 'Verdadero';
    }else{
        $_POST['orden-localidad'] = 'Falso';
        }   

    if($_POST['orden-provincia']){
        $_POST['orden-provincia'] = 'Verdadero';
    }else{
        $_POST['orden-provincia'] = 'Falso';
        }   

    if($_POST['orden-tlf1']){
        $_POST['orden-tlf1'] = 'Verdadero';
    }else{
        $_POST['orden-tlf1'] = 'Falso';
        }   

    if($_POST['orden-tlf2']){
        $_POST['orden-tlf2'] = 'Verdadero';
    }else{
        $_POST['orden-tlf2'] = 'Falso';
        }   

    if($_POST['orden-imagen']){
        $_POST['orden-imagen'] = 'Verdadero';
    }else{
        $_POST['orden-imagen'] = 'Falso';
        }

    if($_POST['orden-email']){
        $_POST['orden-email'] = 'Verdadero';
    }else{
        $_POST['orden-email'] = 'Falso';
        }


    //// Recoger checkbox visualizar ////
    if($_POST['visualizar-direccion']){
        $_POST['visualizar-direccion'] = 'Verdadero';
    }else{
        $_POST['visualizar-direccion'] = 'Falso';
        }

    if($_POST['visualizar-cp']){
        $_POST['visualizar-cp'] = 'Verdadero';
    }else{
        $_POST['visualizar-cp'] = 'Falso';
        }

    if($_POST['visualizar-localidad']){
        $_POST['visualizar-localidad'] = 'Verdadero';
    }else{
        $_POST['visualizar-localidad'] = 'Falso';
        }   

    if($_POST['visualizar-provincia']){
        $_POST['visualizar-provincia'] = 'Verdadero';
    }else{
        $_POST['visualizar-provincia'] = 'Falso';
        }   

    if($_POST['visualizar-tlf1']){
        $_POST['visualizar-tlf1'] = 'Verdadero';
    }else{
        $_POST['visualizar-tlf1'] = 'Falso';
        }   

    if($_POST['visualizar-tlf2']){
        $_POST['visualizar-tlf2'] = 'Verdadero';
    }else{
        $_POST['visualizar-tlf2'] = 'Falso';
        }   

    if($_POST['visualizar-imagen']){
        $_POST['visualizar-imagen'] = 'Verdadero';
    }else{
        $_POST['visualizar-imagen'] = 'Falso';
        }

    if($_POST['visualizar-email']){
        $_POST['visualizar-email'] = 'Verdadero';
    }else{
        $_POST['visualizar-email'] = 'Falso';
        }
    /*
    echo $_POST['orden-email'] ;
    echo $_POST['visualizar-email'] ;
    */

    ////Datos db
    $usuario = "usuario";
    $password = "pass";
    $servidor = "IP_BD";
    $basededatos = "tabla";

    ////Crear conexion
    $conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password)
    or die("No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos");

    ////Seleccionar db
    $db = mysqli_select_db($conexion, $basededatos)
    or die("uppppss! No se ha podido conectar a la base de datos");

    ////Establecer y realizar consulta
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Campos_CFG VALUES 
            ('Dirección',$_POST['orden-direccion'],$_POST['visualizar-direccion']),
            ('Dirección',$_POST['orden-direccion'],$_POST['visualizar-direccion']),
            ('CP',$_POST['orden-cp'],$_POST['visualizar-cp']),
            ('Localidad',$_POST['orden-localidad'],$_POST['visualizar-localidad']),
            ('Provincia',$_POST['orden-provincia'],$_POST['visualizar-provincia']),
            ('Teléfono1',$_POST['orden-tlf1'],$_POST['visualizar-tlf1']),
            ('Teléfono2',$_POST['orden-tlf2'],$_POST['visualizar-tlf2']),
            ('Imagen',$_POST['orden-imagen'],$_POST['visualizar-imagen']),
            ('Email',$_POST['orden-email'],$_POST['visualizar-email']);";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)
    or die("Algo ha ido mal en la consulta a la base de datos");
    mysql_query($sql);

    ////Cerrar conexion 
    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>`
```

Comment: Esto es una pregunta/sugerencia, paralela a tu pregunta: ¿son esos datos de conexión a la BD los reales? Si es así, sería prudente que edites tu pregunta, usando valores inventados, ya que si no, estás dejando la puerta abierta a cualquiera a entrar en dicha BD. Sölo pregunto.

Comment: Puedes poner esto al principio del archivo y editar la respuesta con los errors que te da? `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` No acabo de entender el problema o el error que tienes... Además, te he propuesto una edición de la pregunta, pues tienes información sensible en ella que no debería estar a la vista

Comment: Tal como dice @msabate, necesitamos que nos digas el error exacto que te da este procedimiento, si es que te da alguno.... Si es un error al ejecutar el query, puedes obtener su detalle imprimiendo en pantalla los valores de `mysqli_error` y `mysqli_errno`.

Comment: Me da error justo en la línea 127 (me da 'fallo de sintaxis'), al hacer el 'insert into' la siguiente linea, no se si es por poner los parametros recogidos o que, porque luego quito los $_POST y no me da fallo

Comment: ¿Intentaste hacer el `insert` de un solo registro por vez? Ya que si mal no recuerdo, hacer un `insert` en modo "bulk" (muchos registros a la vez) no es soportado por estas funciones... Como siempre digo, lee la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php) ;)

Comment: y como puedo hacerlo entonces? Es que necesitaría añadir todos los valores de una vez.

Comment: Puedes hacer un arreglo con los datos, y luego recorrerlo con un `for` (o `foreach`), de modo que en cada iteración, ejecutes un `insert` ;)

Comment: Pffff... Igualmente me sigue dando fallo de sintaxis...He puesto solo que añada un registro y ahi sigue el fallo...

Comment: Otra sugerencia: quita el `;` del final del query. No sé si importe, pero a nada...

Comment: A todo esto, ¿has corroborado qué hay dentro del `$sql`? Podrías empezar por revisar eso XD... A veces nos llegan mal los datos (vacíos, por ej.), o no estás encapsulando entre comillas un valor de cadena, etc. Dale un `print_r($sql);` previo a ejecuta el query.

Comment: Estás usando funciones mysqli_* (de una manera insegura y vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL) pero luego, al hacer el query, haces mysql_query.

Comment: Deberías [edit] la pregunta para añadir la información que pones en los comentarios. Además de añadir más detalles: ¿Cuál es el error específico que te da? (error de sintaxis es algo muy genérico) ¿Cuál es la estructura de la tabla en la base de datos? ¿Cuál es la sentencia generada?

Comment: Ten en cuenta para un futuro una regla que te ahorrará horas de trabajo: **cuando algo está fallando, depura eso que está fallando**.   ¿Está fallando la consulta? Entonces depura tu variable `$sql`, o sea, **imprímela: `echo $sql;`  y revísala ...** si es posible, intenta ejecutarla directamente en la base de datos para ver si funciona. Por ejemplo, tienes una variable `$_POST['visualizar-direccion']` que se repite varias veces, pero resulta que en tu formulario no hay ningún elemento que se llame `visualizar-direccion`... No olvides la regla: **depura lo que está fallando.**